# Set date for 'datepicker' doesn't work - jQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to set up a calendar with a specific marked day (fix day). For example 30-04-2015 in the calendar where will not possible select another month or day, only show that specify day.

Similar to the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILFbJ.png

I'm using jQueryIU to do it but I can not get it.

Here it's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/andresgl/mr7aokod/3/

HTML

jQuery

```
(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(  
                {
                    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                    hideIfNoPrevNext: false,
                    maxDate: "+1m",
                    minDate: "+1m",
                }
            );
        });
    })(jQuery);

    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", "04/30/2014" );
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

The problem is if I not declare this parameters:

```
           {
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                hideIfNoPrevNext: false,
                maxDate: "+1m",
                minDate: "+1m",
            }
```

The setDate works, but the parameters doesn't work and If I declare the parameters, the setDate doesn't work.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", "04/30/2014" );
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong or where is the mistake and how can I fix it, please?

BTW: I was following the datepicker documentation: api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will suit your needs but  you and can set min and max as dates as well.  Something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(  
            {
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                defaultDate: new Date(2015, 04, 04),
                maxDate: new Date(2015, 04, 04),
                minDate: new Date(2015, 04, 04),
                hideIfNoPrevNext: false                
            }
        );
    });
});
```

**[UPDATED Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr7aokod/7/)**

Alternatively, you need to set the date before you limit the range:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", "04/05/2015" ).datepicker(  
    {
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        /*defaultDate: new Date(2015, 04, 04),*/
        maxDate: new Date(2015, 05, 04),
        minDate: new Date(2015, 05, 04),
        hideIfNoPrevNext: false                
     }
 );
```

**[UPDATED Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mr7aokod/8/)**

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The first one works perfectly! I think it's not the best way because I have to declare two options but works! (I will use it) The second one doesn't work if it's set the date before. If you change the date will set the date set it in maxDate and minDate.  -- Thank you so much!!